# How to alloc memory in structure so it will be continuous

Tags: c, malloc, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to make continuous structure in memory? I have this structure:

```
struct QUESTION
{
    unsigned char *qname;
    unsigned short qtype;
    unsigned short qclass;
};
```

And I want to allocate *qname as string, and I also want that qtype and qclass will be in memory just after *qname string. I need it save to buffer:

```
unsigned char buf[65536];
struct QUESTION *qu = NULL;
qu = (struct QUESTION *)&buf;
```

And I need to ensure, that it will be in buffer in this order: entirely *qname string, qtype and qclass.
My problem is, that I think, when I allocate memory (with malloc()) for *qname (what I must do, because i need to put string there) it will not allocate memory in buf, but somewhere else. So how can I allocate memory in way I want?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Most compilers will put `qtype` and `qclass` immediately after the pointer `qname`, which means they can't possibly be immediately after some `char` object `qname[i]`.

Comment: So you think, that what I need is impossible?

Comment: Is the string in the buffer truly (a) first in the buffer and (b) variable-length?  If so, there is no single C structure that will do what you want.  Creating a structure to match the buffer is inevitably going to be a two- or more step process.

Comment: As an aside, even if you could get this to work, you don't need to set `qu` to `NULL` if you're going to turn around and point it at the buffer, and when you do point it at the buffer, you don't need the '&': saying `qu = (struct QUESTION *)buf` is more correct.

Comment: If the string in the buffer were fixed length, you could use `struct QUESTION
{
    unsigned char qname[NAMELEN];
    unsigned short qtype;
    unsigned short qclass;
};`

Comment: There is no way to do this in a standard-conforming way in general. Also, **why do you believe you need this?**

Comment: @EOF I need this, because I need to send query to DNS server and it need to be this three things continuous in my query...

Comment: Yeah... you will need to mess about with a pointer to the end of the string, then load in the other fields just after.  I can see no easier solution:(

Comment: Sending bytes over a network is just sending those bytes. They don't need to be in any particular computer memory at all.

Answer (score 1):

Many teachers don't take the time to fully explain why "pointers" are needed for strings rather than just having the string.

An integer is 4 bytes (or 2, or 8, depending on the computer). A floating point value is 6 bytes (or 4, or 8, also depending). The problem is, a string doesn't have a known number of bytes. Whether it's `"Hi!"` or `"My name is Inigo Montoya"`, you can't know how long a string is *at compile time*. So, to store a string, or pass one to a function, you can't. Instead, you put it **somewhere else**, and use a *pointer* to that string - which is what the `*` is.

A `char *` is a pointer to the *first* character of the string. By convention, every character *after* that is also part of the string - until you get to a `NUL`. This has the value `0` - which is different from `'0'`. You want a string to be able to hold a phone number (`"The phone number is 1-800-800-8000"`), so you need to be able to store a `'0'` (which has the value `48`). A `NUL` has literally the value of `0` - as a `char`, it's written as `'\0'`. Luckily, the compiler puts a `NUL` on the end of every string for you.

So you've got a string; say `const char question[] = "What do you get when you multiply six by nine?"`. See how I've declared `question` as an array? Many teachers say you should declare it as a `const char *` (or `const char * const`) - but that's wrong! Why? If you declare `const char * const hi = "Hi!"`, then what you're declaring is four bytes to hold the values `'H'`, `'i'`, `'!'` and `'\0'` somewhere or other - and then four ***more*** bytes to store a pointer to point to them, called `hi`! And that's not what you want.

Now, `question` is sitting in memory, at (say) `0x1000`. Any pointer to that string is exactly 4 bytes in size (or 2, or 8...) - but they all hold the value `0x1000`. Your `QUESTION` structure has a pointer to the string, so `QUESTION` is 4 bytes, plus two lots of 2 bytes (`short`s are 2 bytes), for a total of **8** bytes.

What you *want* is a large structure that holds the following:

`"What do you get when you multiply six by nine?\0"` `qtype` `qclass`

And that's where you need to do memory manipulation rather than straightforward C/C++ structures.

One technique is to put the fixed part of the structure *first*, followed by the variable string. Depending on your compiler, you can do that as follows:

```
struct QUESTION
{
    unsigned short qtype;
    unsigned short qclass;
    unsigned char  qname[];
};
```

See what I've done? The first two variables are of a known size, so need to go first. The last variable is an array - but of unknown size. You cannot follow this with any more variables. Note that only recent compilers allow this! Earlier compilers allowed you to use `qname[0]` to indicate "unknown size" - your compiler may complain at either of these...

Assuming you get the above to compile, you've now got two more problems:

1. What is `sizeof(QUESTION)`?
2. How do I get the actual question into `qname[]`?

The answer to (1) is obvious - but not what you want. It's simply `4` - the size of the two `short`s. That makes sense, because you haven't given the size of the array. Thus, if you use `malloc()`, you need to specify both the size of `QUESTION` **plus** the size of `question`:

```
QUESTION *q = (QUESTION *)malloc(sizeof(QUESTION) + strlen(question) + 1);
```

See what I've done here? I've asked `malloc()` to allocate enough memory for the `QUESTION` structure, ***plus*** the length of `question`, ***plus*** one more for the final `NUL`.

You can then do things like:

```
q->qtype = PHILOSOPHICAL;
q->qclass = FUNNY;
```

But to actually get the question itself into `q`, you need to move the bytes from `0x1000` into where `q` points:

```
strcpy(q->qname, question);
```

That will copy the characters from `question` into `q` at the right place - including the final `NUL`